# ros tutorial file not found

Tags: ros, nodes, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently doing the  following ros tutorial on understanding nodes

(http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes)

For this tutorial it is using a lightweight simulator

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
```

But when I  am typing this code it is saying

`bash: indigo: No such file or directory`

kindly help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218172/ros-tutorial-file-not-found/) by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's `ros-indigo-ros-tutorials`, not `ros-<indigo>-ros-tutorials`.

This is clearly (well perhaps not) stated in the tutorial text:

> Replace '`<distro>`' with the name of your ROS distribution (e.g. hydro, groovy, electric, fuerte etc.)

Note it instructs you to replace `<distro>`, including the `<` and `>` characters.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1